# JQuery: If a custom class contains a number greater than 'x' add CSS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add css to a assigned span class if it contains a number higher than 55, also this must on a page load and not a button trigger.

Thanks any help would be great.

Example below: (currently not working)

```
<span class="subTotalPrice">10</span>
<span class="subTotalPrice">5</span>
<span class="subTotalPrice">125</span>
<span class="subTotalPrice">55</span>

<script>
$(".subTotalPrice:contains(> 55)").css({'color':'red', 'text-decoration':'underline'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good way of doing that using jQuery's [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('.subTotalPrice').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 55;
}).css({'color':'red', 'text-decoration':'underline'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is excellent. Also if I wanted to target another class and add 'visibility':'visible'what would I need to add to this code.

Comment: If you just wanted to target every element of that class? `$('.className').css('visibility', 'visible');`

Comment: I mean only if there is a number highier than 55, show a class. ie  $('.subTotalPrice').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 55;
})('#show').css('visibility', 'visible');

Comment: Ah, I see. That would be the same as the code I gave in the answer, only substitute your class name for "subTotalPrice" and change `css({bla bla bla});` to `css('visibility','visible');`

Comment: Sorry for being a little unclear. I would like to still check if .subTotalPrice is over 55 and if it is, change #show class to visible.

Comment: Ah -- you don't want to do all that in one statement. Try this: `if ( parseInt( $('.subTotalPrice').html() ) > 55) $('.show').show();`

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work if there is a dollar sign in the string (ie $120). Is there any work to adjust the code slightly to accommodate for this?

Comment: If you mean a dollar sign in the innerHTML of the class that you're using parseInt() with, try using the following: `parseInt($('.className').html().match(/\d+/)) > 55`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.subTotalPrice').each(function(){
        if(parseInt($(this).text, 10) > 55){
            $(this).css({'color':'red', 'text-decoration':'underline'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why but this code does not seem to work? Am I missing something?