# jQuery logical equivalent to .contains()

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery equivalent to the .contains() selector that works with numbers?

For example if I want to select all elements with inner value > 0.

Let's take this as an example. I want the selector to grab p id 2 and 3 and change the font-weight to bold.

```
<p id=1>0</p>
<p id=2>2</p>
<p id=3>1</p>
```

So I want to replace the contains() part below with something that works with logical operators.

```
$("td:contains(> 0)").css( "font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: Have you looked at this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9304998/7599559

Comment: you can use filter to achieve this functionality

Comment: Thanks! Solved it with the .filter()